Find the value of $\frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{3}}} + \frac{2-\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{3}}}$ .

Find the value of $\frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{3}}} + \frac{2-\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{3}}}$ not the naive way but using polynomials .

I'm letting $\alpha = \sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}, \beta = \sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}$ which doesn't seems to work nor letting $\alpha = 2 + \sqrt{3}, \beta = 2 - \sqrt{3}$ seems to help much either.
Are there any hints I'm not getting any good observations other than they are reciprocals of each other?

What does "using polynomials" mean? Have you been given an example of solving a problem by using polynomials?

https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7B2%2B%5Csqrt%7B3%7D%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7B2%7D%20%2B%20%5Csqrt%7B2%20%2B%20%5Csqrt%7B3%7D%7D%7D%20%2B%20%5Cfrac%7B2-%5Csqrt%7B3%7D%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7B2%7D%20-%20%5Csqrt%7B2%20-%20%5Csqrt%7B3%7D%7D%7D%24&p=1

Notice that $$2\pm \sqrt{3} = {4\pm 2\sqrt{3}\over 2} = {(\sqrt{3}\pm 1)^2\over 2}$$
So
$$\frac{2\pm\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2} \pm \sqrt{2 \pm \sqrt{3}}} = \sqrt2 \cdot {2\pm \sqrt{3}\over 3\pm \sqrt{3}} = \sqrt{2}\cdot {3\pm \sqrt{3}\over 6}$$
and thus the result is $\sqrt{2}$.

OP explicitly wrote, "not the naive way but using polynomials".

Let $$S = \frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{3}}} + \frac{2-\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{3}}}$$
Let us assume that $\alpha = 2 + \sqrt{3}$ and $\beta = 2 - \sqrt{3}$, then $\alpha + \beta = 4$ and $\alpha\beta = 1$.
Now observe that $(1 - \sqrt{3})^{2} = 2\beta$ and $(1 + \sqrt{3})^{2} = 2\alpha$. One thing to note here is that $\alpha, \beta$ both are positive real numbers, so $\sqrt{\alpha}$ and $\sqrt{\beta}$ are also positive. So we choose $\sqrt{\alpha} = \frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $\sqrt{\beta} = \frac{\sqrt{3} - 1}{\sqrt{2}}$, which implies $\sqrt{\beta} + \sqrt{\alpha} = \sqrt{2}\sqrt{3}$.
$$ \begin{align} S &= \frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{2} + \frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}} + \frac{\beta}{\sqrt{2} - \frac{\sqrt{3} - 1}{\sqrt{2}}}
\\ &= \frac{\alpha\sqrt{2}}{3 + \sqrt{3}} + \frac{\beta\sqrt{2}}{3 - \sqrt{3}}
\\ &= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}(\frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{3} + 1} + \frac{\beta}{\sqrt{3} -1})
\\ &= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}(\frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\alpha}} + \frac{\beta}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\beta}})
\\ &= \frac{\sqrt{\beta} + \sqrt{\alpha}}{ \sqrt{3}}\\ &= \sqrt{2}.\end{align}$$
